# BECAUSE WITH PAST PERFECT OR SIMPLE

Tags: grammar

-1

I was tired because I hadn't slept or didn't sleep.

I cried because my dad slapped or had slapped me.

I went to restaurant yesterday but could not order anything because I left or had left my wallet at home.

I woke up late because I forgot or had forgotten to set the alarm.

I woke up late and realized I overslept or had overslept.

What's the more correct and natural choice in every sentence?

Comment: @stangdon No it doesn't answer the question. I see that someone has voted to close this because it it a duplicate, but this is only a duplicate of the same question migrated from EL&U where the OP was told to ask it here - which they have. Note that the OP hasn't got an answer to either version of their post at the time of this comment.  Rather unfair to down vote it when the OP was only doing as they were told.

Comment: If there are two versions of the question here now, it still seems reasonable to keep only one.

Comment: @PeterJennings A close vote isn't a down vote.  It just doesn't make sense, as Divizna says, to keep two versions of the same question.

Comment: that was my first ever question on this site and got removed i was told to ask this another page because I asked it on a wrong page but now its deleted without any answer? can i post it again will i get answer or that will also get removed by that one?

Comment: @RomyLearner  Your original question is still here:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/329556/because-with-past-perfect-or-past-simple